# Dynamic hide by id in array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have ids in an array in javascript. I need to loop through the ids and hide them using jQuery.

```js
var trIds = ["trVipQuota", "trVipQuota1", "trHigherOfficial", "trSportAchievement",
  "trSportAchievement1", "trSpecialConcession", "trSpecialConcession1",
  "trSiblingConcession", "trSiblingConcession1", "trSiblingConcession2", "trTransferFrom", "trTransferTo"
];

var i;
for (i = 0; i < trIds.length; i++) {
  $("'#" + trIds + "'").hide();
}
```

Comment: What’s the question?

Comment: What is the problem here? Is your code not working?

Comment: in Console.log it working properly but its does not work as jquery statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For do that use Array object and iterate with **forEach()** like that:

```js
$(function(){

  let trIds = new Array("trVipQuota", "trVipQuota1", "trHigherOfficial","trSportAchievement", "trSportAchievement1","trSpecialConcession","trSpecialConcession1", "trSiblingConcession","trSiblingConcession1","trSiblingConcession2","trTransferFrom","trTransferTo" );

  trIds.forEach(function(element){

    $(`#${element}`).hide();

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="trVipQuota">vip 1</p>
<p id="trVipQuota1">vip 2</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the explicit loop by building a selector string from the array using `map()` and `join()`, like this:

```js
var trIds = ["trVipQuota", "trVipQuota1", "trHigherOfficial", "trSportAchievement", "trSportAchievement1", "trSpecialConcession", "trSpecialConcession1", "trSiblingConcession", "trSiblingConcession1", "trSiblingConcession2", "trTransferFrom", "trTransferTo"];

let selector = trIds.map(id => `#${id}`).join(',');
$(selector).hide();
```

Also note that you can avoid the need even for this by simply just using a class on all the target elements instead.